# How to view locally stored webpages on Android?

Tags: android, webview

I am new to android programming and my problem is that i am not able to view my website on my android phone. The entire website is store locally.

In the screenshot you can see that the page is stored in res/assets.about_us.html and I have given this in path.

[here is the link to screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wHealzmk4JQXhkTEIwdzVQaWc/edit?usp=sharing). Sorry but i don't have enough points to post it here.

I have added this to manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

here is my code

```
private WebView browser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_aboutus);

        WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.yourwebview);

        WebSettings settings = browser.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        browser.loadUrl("file:///res/assets/about_us.html");

    }
```

here is the error

```
08-12 20:34:20.562  12606-12682/samvid.android.com.calcisamultimatecalculator E/AndroidProtocolHandler﹕ Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/about_us.html
08-12 20:34:20.572  12606-12606/samvid.android.com.calcisamultimatecalculator W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
08-12 20:34:20.602  12606-12606/samvid.android.com.calcisamultimatecalculator W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
08-12 20:34:20.702  12606-12606/samvid.android.com.calcisamultimatecalculator I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png", source: data:text/html,chromewebdata (12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things required to make this work:

1. Make sure your assets folder is in the root of your app (that is, not inside res, but basically beside it).
2. Use the correct path: "file:///android_asset/about_us.html"

Comment: since the name of the folder is assets then in path do i need to use "file:///android_asset/about_us.html" or "file:///assets/about_us.html"??

Comment: android_asset ... I know, it's not straightforward. But it works ;)

Comment: not working for me, i have added more details in the question, can you please look into it and then tell me what is the problem??

Comment: Are you using android_asset everywhere? Is your assets folder OUTSIDE of res?

Comment: my assets folder is our side res folder and its name is "asset". do i need to change name or anything?? also my webpage contains css/html files, do they work in webview??

Comment: The name has to be assets, not asset. HTML definitely works, CSS should, too.

Comment: finally it worked, thanks....problem was with spelling. thanks again for your help.